How to load a Contivo generated java class file at runtime using contivo-runtime-6.3?
I am using Contivo Analyst version 3.10 to do mapping between 2 XML documents. I want to pass the contivo map generated class instance for doing transformation by Transformer/TransformAny object from contivo-runtime-6.3 lib. Please suggest me the proper way to pass the class instance or provid me any doc/example to do the same.
Error: Transformer class is not supporting any Class<?> instance as a constrictor param, and TransformAny class not loading the class instance.
Transformation:
   Class<?> transformClass = new DynamicClassLoader(Constant.path_download).load("MyContivoGenerated.java");
    Transformer transformer = new Transformer(transformClass);
    List<String> target = transformer.toTargetString();
    this.resultHandler.process(transformer.getResults());
    
    TransformAny transformAny = new TransformAny(transformClass);
    String target = transformAny.toTargetString();
    resultHandler.processOld(transformAny.getResults());

